# Анализ выполнения android приложения?

Tags: android

Всем доброго времени суток.

Пишу сейчас небольшое приложение, и по-неопытности оно у меня получается не оптимизированным, меня интересует можно ли в момент выполнения приложения в *GenyMoution* каким то образом проверить количество классов которые создает приложение?

Comment: Для начала, вы путаете определение класса и объекта.

Comment: Как раз недавно была статья на Хабре по теме http://habrahabr.ru/company/edison/blog/271761/

Comment: Я имел в виду, экземпляры классов)
За статью спасибо, похоже - это то, что я искал!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если делать проект в **Android Studio**, то можно отслеживать количество свободной и занятой оперативной памяти для вашего приложения. Нажимаете на вкладку (внизу) **Android Monitor**, далее жмякаете вкладку **Memory**, там динамически можно отслеживать свободную и занятую память по графику, также там можно смотреть объекты в стеке и куче. Посмотрите [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/company/edison/blog/271761), которую посоветовал **@Eugene Krivenja**, там описано это более подробно